# Regex with preg_match_all only matches first occurance

Tags: php, regex

This regex `/\@[a-z0-9]+/i` with `preg_match_all()` only matches the first occurance of @a-z?

Using this in php: `preg_match_all('/\@[a-z0-9]+/i', $input, $matches)`

Comment: What is your `$input`?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It matches multiple occurences. You're using it wrong. (Hint: fewer guessed answers if you provide actual code and context.)

Answer (score 1):

Simple mistake made?

This matches all instances of `@` followed by any character of: `a-z` or `A-Z` or `0-9` (1 or more times).

Also you don't need to escape the `@` here.

```
<?php

$text = <<<T
@fooo
@bar1234
@stackoverflow
T;

preg_match_all('/@[a-z0-9]+/i', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => @fooo
            [1] => @bar1234
            [2] => @stackoverflow
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It will match one and only one @, and then one or more letter/digits  (because of the +).

Your regexp is also case-insensitive with the i at the end.

So it'll match '@a', '@aaaAAAAzZZeeEErrRttT1234', but not '@@aaa'.

Comment: It'll match `@@aaa` just fine. It'll just match the `@aaa` part of it.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex in combination with preg_match_all is correct. Just write a small test script if you're not sure:

```
 <?php
 $input = '@a @b';
 preg_match_all('/\@[a-z0-9]+/i', $input, $matches);
 var_dump($matches);
 ?>
```

If you want an easier regular expression you can just use `/@\w+/`.

Comment: There is no need to escape `@`

Comment: That's right. I just copied Sam's regex. The easier regex probably is ``'/@\w+/'``.

Comment: `\w` matches also `_` (underscore).